# SQL sum values from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Hobby, whose snippet is as follows:

```
Name    Activity    Hours

John    Hiking      .5
Sam     Cycling     .5
Sam     Swimming    1
Sam     Hiking      .5
John    Running     1
Sam     Sailing     1
```

For every person X in (X, Y), I would like to find the sum of hours of activities where X and Y don't have in common. For example, if John = X and Sam = Y, then it would yield 1, since Running is the only activity John has that Sam doesn't.

My code is as follows:

```
select a.Name, b.Name, sum(a.Hours)
from Hobby a, Hobby b
where a.Name <> b.Name and a.Activity <> b.Activity
group by a.Name, b.Name;
```

However, this gave me a wrong answer. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find this to be a tricky question.  My original approach was going to use a `full outer join`.  But then I realized that if there is no match on the activity in one name, then I'm not going to have the name either.

So, the following query works by getting a list of all pairs of names.  This is an ordered list, so a given pair of names only appears once.  Then this is joined to the `Hobby` table twice, using `left outer join` to get the matches.  The key, though, is that when there is no match, the row with `Activity` on it is still present, but with a `NULL` value.

The `where` clause finds all `Activity`s that have a `NULL` in either table.  These are the ones that don't match.  Then it is a simple matter of just adding up the hours:

```
select names.Name1, names.Name2, sum(coalesce(h1.hours, h2.hours))
from (select distinct h1.Name as name1, h2.Name as name2
      from Hobby h1 cross join Hobby h2
      where h1.Name < h2.Name
     ) names left outer join
     Hobby h1
     on names.name1 = h1.name left outer join
     Hobby h2
     on names.name2 = h2.name and
        h1.Activity = h2.Activity
where h1.Activity is null or h2.Activity is null
group by names.Name1, names.Name2;
```

Comment: This isn't symmetric `hours(X, Y) != hours(Y, X)` in general, Change the `<` to a `!=`

Answer (score 0):

your from clause reads

```
FROM Hobby a, Hobby b
```

Putting a comma in the from clause means "CROSS JOIN" which means each row in the first table are correlated with every row in the second table. Given your where clause I would think this gives some pretty big numbers.

your query needs to be a bit different:

```
select sum(hours) 
from hobby 
where name = 'John' 
  and activity not in (
    select activity 
    from hobby 
    where name = 'Sam'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the list of people and activities, and join to it a list of all other people, and test whether the other people also take part in that activity, it ought to do the trick.

```
with
  cte_unique_names as (
    select distinct name
    from   hobby)
select
  h.name participates,
  n.name does_not_participate,
  sum(hours) hours
from
  hobby h
cross join
  cte_unique_names n
where
  n.name != h.name and
  not exists (
    select null
    from   hobby h2
    where  h2.name     = n.name and
           h2.activity = h.activity)
group by
  h.name,
  n.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of the underlying results before the group by. Consider only rows where table a is `John, Hiking`. In your query you would have

```
John    Hiking    0.5    John    Hiking      0.5
John    Hiking    0.5    Sam     Cycling     0.5
John    Hiking    0.5    Sam     Swimming    1
John    Hiking    0.5    Sam     Hiking      0.5
John    Hiking    0.5    John    Running     1
John    Hiking    0.5    Sam     Sailing     1
```

With your where clause, you'd remove the John rows and the Hiking rows from table b leaving:

```
John    Hiking    0.5    Sam     Cycling     0.5
John    Hiking    0.5    Sam     Swimming    1
John    Hiking    0.5    Sam     Sailing     1
```

So you're going to be counting these hours three times in the `John, Sam` set.

Here's a way to adjust it, while still only using each table once:

```
Select
    a.Name,
    b.Name Name2,
    Sum(a.Hours) / count(distinct b.activity) 
       - Sum(case when a.Activity = b.Activity then a.Hours else 0 end) as Hours
From
    Hobby a,
    Hobby b
Where
    a.Name != b.Name
Group By
    a.Name,
    b.Name
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d626/2)</kbd>**

Comment: I think that if you join to a distinct list of names instead of the complete hobby table you would not need the division by the count of activities.

Comment: You're right, but I was trying to adapt the OP's query as little as possible.